# get the text of a div

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to get the text from a div using only javascript.

I started with jQuery using the following code:

```
var divText = $("div.Xr3").html();
```

Then for my JavaScript I tried:

```
var divText = document.getElementsByClassName("Xr3").innerHtml;
```

Which returns undefined. How can I accomplish this using JavaScript only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a live array of HTML elements, so you can't access `innerHTML` directly like this. You will either have to loop over its results, or if you know there's only one, apply `[0]` to it before accessing `innerHTML`.

```
var divTexts = [];
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("Xr3");
var numDivs = divs.length;
while (var i = 0; i < numDivs; i++) {
  divTexts.push(divs[i].innerHtml);
}
```

or, in a single-element scenario,

```
var divText = document.getElementsByClassName("Xr3")[0].innerHtml;
```

Answer (score 1):

If `Xr3` is used one time, you can use

`var divText = document.getElementsByClassName("Xr3")[0].innerHtml;`